# How to tell if plugin has been network activated

Tags: plugins, multisite, options

I have the following lines of code that add the settings link and setup for my plugin:

```
add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'admin_settings_menu')); // Add menu to options
add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'admin_settings_init')); // Add admin init functions
```

Now because of the nature of my plugin if the plugin is *Network Installed* then the settings should only be available to the network admin not the individual site admins.

Is there a way to check if the plugin is Network Installed so I can wrap an if statement round it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `is_plugin_active_for_network( $plugin )`